# Get a File text as a String using Enumerator/Iteratee

Tags: scala, stream, playframework-2.0

Looking into the Play Iteratee (Handling Data Streams reactively), I have an Array[Byte] Enumerator (from a file stream), and I need to get the string representation of this enumerator (I need the text as a string of the stream)

The enumerator sample I have is:

```
Enumerator.fromFile(new File("test.txt"))
```

I was able to solve it using the fold:

```
val concat: Iteratee[Array[Byte], String] = 
  Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], String]("")((finalString, array) => 
    finalString + new String(array.map(_.toChar)))

val textString = Await.result(
  Iteratee.flatten(fileEnumerator |>> concat).run, 1 seconds)
```

any other simpler solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Iteratee.consume`. It will concatenate all of the input into one `Array[Byte]`. You can then convert to a `String`.

```
val concat = Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]().map(x => new String(x))
```

It is necessary to do the conversion to a string only after the entire array is available. Individual bytes cannot be mapped to characters because many characters are not a single byte in length.

Answer (score 0):

### The other way to get the whole string would be,

```
Iteratee.flatten(
 fileEnumerator.map(chunk => new String(chunk)) |>> Iteratee.consume[String]()).run
 .onSuccess {case wholeUniverse => println(wholeUniverse)}
```

### Try on play console

```
$ play console

scala> import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Enumerator, Iteratee}
import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Enumerator, Iteratee}

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import java.io.File
import java.io.File

scala> val fileEnumerator = Enumerator.fromFile(new File("build.sbt"))
fileEnu: play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator$$anon$4@650b0c9

scala> val future = Iteratee.flatten(fileEnumerator.map(x => new String(x)) |>> Iteratee.consume[String]()).run
future: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@4134f577

scala> future.onSuccess {case x => println(x)}
import play.Project._

name := "shaharma-backend"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

playScalaSettings

resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.6.1"
)
```

[I myself learned something](http://prayagupd-dreamspace.blogspot.com/2016/10/consuming-scala-play-enumerator.html) so though would be helplful.